# Create multiple html tables from database table using any PHP loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to create a piece of PHP code that will create an HTML table for every array in my database table. The point of this is that a new HTML table will  be created if a new array is added in the database.
This is my code as it is now:

```
<?php
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>JOY FLOWERS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outter">
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.php">Proionta</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.html">Epikoinonia</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="leftcol"></div>
            <div id="midcol">

            <?php
            $con = mysql_connect ( "localhost", "root", "tei@123" ) or die ( "Αποτυχία σύνδεσης με τον Server<br />" );

            mysql_select_db ( "proionta", $con ) or die ( "Αποτυχία σύνδεσης με την database<br />" );
            $query = "SELECT * FROM proionta";

            mysql_query ( "SET NAMES 'utf8';", $con );
            mysql_query ( "SET CHARACTERS SET 'utf8';", $con );

            $result = mysql_query ( $query, $con );
            $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result );
            foreach ($row as $result);{

            ?>  

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th><img src="<?php echo $row["eikona"]?>" width="100%"</th>
                        </tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row["proion"]; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row["timh"];?> ευρώ /τεμάχιο</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                     <?php  }?>

            </div>
            <div id="rightcol"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use loops such as foreach and while but I failed.. considering this is my first ever PHP project I feel a bit lost in all the information I received in the last couple of days so I could really use some help on this one..

This is the foreach loop I used. I feel like $row and $result should be the other way around but this is the only way I don't get an error.. It only creates a table for the first array though.

Thanks in advance and please forgive any english mistakes

Comment: Please show your foreach or while loop not working, then we can point you in the right direction. Dont just leave a gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result )) {
        ?>  
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img src="<?php echo $row["eikona"]?>" width="100%"</th>
                    </tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["proion"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row["timh"];?> ευρώ /τεμάχιο</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
    <?php } ?>php
```

Comment: thanks a lot man.. i knew it was something really simple, just couldnt figure it out

Comment: You may find this link useful.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php  Particularly the warning about using mysql_* functions.